# javascript ValueCallback not working in swift

Tags: javascript, html, swift

I have this javascript code below that i want run in swift to extract html but i got the following error: Cannot find ValueCallback in scope.

```
view.evaluateJavascript(
    "(function() { return ('<html>'+document.getElementById('html').innerHTML+'</html>'); })();",
    new ValueCallback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveValue(String html) {
            print(html);
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`evaluateJavascript` function has a different signature

```swift
/* @abstract Evaluates the given JavaScript string.
  @param javaScriptString The JavaScript string to evaluate.
  @param completionHandler A block to invoke when script evaluation completes or fails.
  @discussion The completionHandler is passed the result of the script evaluation or an error.
  Calling this method is equivalent to calling `evaluateJavaScript:inFrame:inContentWorld:completionHandler:` with:
    - A `frame` value of `nil` to represent the main frame
    - A `contentWorld` value of `WKContentWorld.pageWorld`
    */
  open func evaluateJavaScript(_ javaScriptString: String, completionHandler: ((Any?, Error?) -> Void)? = nil)
```

You'd need to change your code to

```swift
view.evaluateJavascript("(function() { return ('<html>'+document.getElementById('html').innerHTML+'</html>'); })();") { value, error in
  print(value)
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i have tried your suggestion. First it indicates me that i need to unwrap value. Then it through error saying unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value. Do you have any idea? Thanks

Comment: @john Yes, the value is optional, so, you'd need to `guard` it. The value is nil because JS code is async. Just add some waiter in your code or change the implementation to the delegate instead of a callback